# ampersand in search querystring

Tags: 2013

We have a custom search box and button that redirects the user to the search page and appends the search query however we noticed that if the query has an ampersand (&) in it the user is redirected to the generic error page.  e.g

search url

http://xxxxxx/search-results?k=test & stuff

redirects to

http://xxxxxx/Pages/PageNotFoundError.aspx?requestUrl=http://xxxxx/search-results

We have tried encoding the querystring but it makes no difference.  Can anyone cast some light on what can be done in this scenrio

Comment: This doesn't behave like that out of the box so I'd point the finger at your redirect logic.  Look closely at the requestUrl param. Does it point to a valid url?

Comment: @DerekGusoff The url is correct and without the & it works as expected.  Everyone is stumped

Answer (score 0):

Handling an ampersand in a search query is just a matter of encoding the querystring. So for your sample of `test & stuff` the querystring should be `?k=test%20%26%20stuff`

If you continue to get a page not found error when using that encoding then likely the search page url is incorrect.

Comment: unfortunately this doesnt work.  It redirects even when encoded.